How much time do I have to save data to local storage when browser visibility changes to hidden?
I want to save page data to local storage upon tab close or reload. I am saving data upon visibilitychange event to hidden. I've read this is the recommended way to do so per Page Lifecycle API and the article Don't lose user and app state, use Page Visibility.
Specifically, beforeunload is not recommended per its usage notes on MDN.
However, I observed that if I close the tab and spend too much time processing the data to be saved (as I am compressing it first, which takes over a second), it does not actually save.
The Page Lifecycle API states the following about Terminated state with comes after Hidden state:

and in-progress tasks may be killed if they run too long.

This documentation links to an article that mentions Event loop processing model, which in turn mentions computeDeadline but it is hard to understand.
How much time do I have to compress and save my data to local browser storage upon browser tab being closed, before the browser kills the processing?

@JaromandaX not recommended. See note at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#usage_notes

as I am compressing it first how much state are you storing in localStorage that takes a second to compress. Have you considered you may be storing too much? Or not compressing it? (I know those two are conflicting suggestions - but clearly, what you are doing isn't working)

Over 5 million characters uncompressed, that's why I have to compress it (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage#Storage_size).
I understand that IndexedDB is probably a better solution (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), but I still want to know what is the time limit.

the time limit may well be browser dependant ... clearly, on the browser you are using over a second is too long - what in the world are you storing though! 5 Megabytes of what!

I am developing a prototype where the frontend receives a JSON from backend that is composed of snapshots of "simulation state". By the time the JSON has about 220 snapshots it crosses the 5 million characters mark. Of course, I could do various optimizations like operate only on the current snapshot and get from a backend database the previous ones only if I need them, etc. but so far I have no backend database yet and I am trying to keep things simple.

Of course, another issue is that not all devices have the same performance. Sure, it may take over a second on your device, but may take much longer on a lower spec device. So, knowing how much time you have is largely irrelevant. The answer to how much time you have is obviously less than over a second on the browser you are using

Another thing to consider is the performance of your compression ... find a much faster implementation that may not compress as much (but still enough for your needs) - what are you using for the compression phase?

not all devices have the same performance - not only that, but not all browsers have the same performance - the CompressionStream API for example is over twice as slow on Firefox compared the the Chromium stable of browsers

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
